# SQL Server Reporting Services Mobile Views

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm about to create a report that will be scheduled to send email updates each night. We're sending emails because we want these reports to be available outside the company firewall on BlackBerrys. This means we're limiting the functionality a fair bit (no drill down, sorting, advanced filtering and only one table worth of data). Is there a way to version this report so that if it's viewed on a handheld it has the minimal functionality but if viewed within the network on a desktop it has all the bells and whistles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could have the subscription mail out the stripped down version of the report and then ahve a link in that report that points back to the full-featured report on the network (basically you'd have 2 different reports)

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry has several mobile options you can springboard from; Personally, I'd lean towards PDF export, since you've stated you don't need all the "bells and whistles". You can set up subscriptions in Report Manager, and have those subscriptions email PDF's out to your Blackberry users. This way, they get the data wherever they happen to be, on the appropriate email address.

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I've heard of) to go about stripping it down for a specific user agent...